# type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list c++

Tags: c++, templates

I recieve the following error: `error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> class AVLTree'`
On this line : `AVLTree<AVLTree> * ptr;`
Is this an illegal use of templates? any work-arounds?

Comment: The `AVLTree` template wants a type as its argument, not a class template. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create an AVL tree which it's nodes are AVL trees

Comment: `AVLTree` is not a type, it's a template that you can instantiate in order to generate a type. You can make a `AVLTree<AVLTree<int>>` or a `AVLTree<AVLTree<std::string>>`, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVLTree takes a template parameter, to the contained type. The contained type is what will actually be contained by it, AVLTree itself can be seen more as a "blueprint".

```cpp
AVLTree<AVLTree<int>>* ptr;
```

Would be a correct usage of this template.
Substitute `int` with whichever type you'd like contained.